Trouble building Docker image with Chrome, Chromium for Selenium and Spring Boot (java17)
I am facing challenges in building Docker images for Chrome on amd64 architecture and Chromium on ARM64 architecture. While the installations seem to proceed without errors, my Spring Boot application and Selenium cannot detect the installed browsers within their respective Docker containers.
Here is the relevant part of the Dockerfile I'm using for chrome and amd64:
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy AS builder
WORKDIR /opt/app/
COPY .mvn/ .mvn/
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline
COPY ./src/ ./src/
RUN ./mvnw clean package -DskipTests
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/app/*.jar"]

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy
COPY ./chrome/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb /tmp/
RUN apt update && apt install -y /tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && apt clean
RUN rm /tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

WORKDIR /opt/app/
COPY ./chromedriver-linux/* /opt/app/chromedriver-linux/
COPY --from=builder /opt/app/target/*.jar /opt/app/app.jar
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/app/app.jar"]

Despite seemingly successful installations of Chrome and Chromium, when running my Spring Boot application with Selenium, the browsers appear undetected. Any assistance on configuring these images correctly for both amd64 and ARM64 architectures would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Information:
Using Selenium version 4.21.0
Spring Boot version 3.3.0
I have successfully run my program on Windows with the latest stable versions of Chrome and Chromedriver downloaded from Google. When attempting to containerize it with Docker on Linux, I expected the program to behave similarly, utilizing the latest stable versions of Chrome and Chromedriver within the Docker container.
